# Sending an Array with input values to a database with php

Tags: php

So bassically I can't seem to send the array with the input values to my database.

I tried sending it seperately, it works, but it only sends the array or the way around. There are no errors.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $services = implode ("|", $_POST['services']);
    mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO klientai (package, name, surname, email, phone, message, services) VALUES('$_POST[package]', '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[surname]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[message]', '$services'");
}
```

Comment: echo $services to check you are getting a string with no special characters (eg quotes) in there.

Comment: everything is OK with the array, no special characters. I just can't seem to add it with other inputs together. Seperately it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mysql_query** function is [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and is not secured, You should use another option.

You can use PDO for example:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

open connection

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

insert method 1

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, sex) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$name, $surname, $sex]);
```

insert method 2

```
$data = [
    'name' => $name,
    'surname' => $surname,
    'sex' => $sex,
];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, sex) VALUES (:name, :surname, :sex)";
 $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute($data);
```

also check https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/insert and 
https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/pdo-for-beginner-part-1

In this method, you don't need to escape your strings for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and it should also solve your problem.

Comment: OP used `mysqli_query` in his code. Your code is not safe against SQL injection. You pointed OP to the best available tutorial, but you haven't used what is written there in your answer.